# Live BSE NSE ticker on my website

Tags: javascript, php, ticker

I want to put live horizontal ticker of BSE and NSE, not the iframe version which I cannot customise the look. Also I need to display stock quote and chart facility. 
I am using php.

Thanks

Comment: This question does not belong on StackOverflow. The expectation on this website is that you have already tried something and it didn't work. If you need general guidance or consultation, you may want to consider hiring a consultant. Check out Careers 2.0 or Elance.

Comment: thanks for your advice. but i have tried a lot and could not drop my junk codes of testing here. available widgets are like www.widgetbox.com but all are iframe things which i cannot customize